# MySQL Searching For Multiple Keywords

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search a mySQL table for long tail keywords displaying the closest or exact matches first, then ordering by `Fixture-Name`.

There has got to be a more intelligent way of doing this... Any and all feedback is appreciated!

```
SELECT * FROM `equipment` 
WHERE (`Fixture-Name` LIKE "%keyword2 keyword1%" || `Description` LIKE "%keyword2 keyword1%"||`Product-Line` LIKE "%keyword2 keyword1%" || `Fixture-Type` LIKE "%keyword2 keyword1%" ||   `Lamp-Watts` LIKE "%keyword2 keyword1%")
UNION

SELECT * FROM `equipment` 
WHERE (`Fixture-Name` LIKE "%keyword2%" || `Description` LIKE "%keyword2%" || `Product-Line` LIKE "%keyword2%" || `Fixture-Type` LIKE "%keyword2%" || `Lamp-Watts` LIKE "%keyword2%")
UNION 

SELECT * FROM `equipment` 
WHERE (`Name` LIKE "%keyword1%" || `Description` LIKE "%keyword1%" || `Product-Line` LIKE "%keyword1%" || `Fixture-Type` LIKE "%keyword1%" || `Lamp-Watts` LIKE "%keyword1%")
```

Comment: If I were you I'd do a loop if this is with PHP or some other level 3 language.

Comment: both good ideas! Thanks! I'll do some exploration of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of application, it would be better to build a `keyword` table, and a `keyword_equipment`, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE keyword (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    word CHAR(127) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX(word)
)

CREATE TABLE keyword_equipment (
    keyword_id INT NOT NULL,
    equipment_id INT NOT NULL,
    weight DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (keyword_id, equipment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (keyword_id) REFERENCES keyword (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (equipment_id) REFERENCES equipment (id),
)
```

Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM keyword AS k
INNER JOIN keyword_equipment AS ke ON ke.keyword_id = k.id
INNER JOIN equipment AS e ON e.id = ke.equipment_id
WHERE k.word IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2')
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY SUM(ke.weight) DESC
```

When inserting or updating `equipment`, make sure you keep both `keyword` and `keyword_equipment` tables up-to-date!